# Unable to pass data to twig file from controller in symfony

Tags: twig, symfony4

I am trying to pass data from the controller to view, but when I passed the data am getting the following error

```
Variable "products" does not exist.
```

PLease find my controller code below

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

USE App\Entity\Product;
use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ProductController extends AbstractController
{
    //#[Route('/product', name: 'app_product')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'ProductController',
        ]);
    }

    public function show(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $products = $entityManager->getRepository(Product::class)->findAll();

        if (!$products) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No product found for id '.$id
            );
        }

        else{
           return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', ['product' => $products]);
        }

        

    }
}
```

Please find my twig template code below

```
<form action="{{ path('home') }}">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <label class="all-label">Product</label>
                                    <div class="input-group mb-3 select-down">
                                        <select class="form-select form-control" aria-label="Default select example" name="product">
                                           
                                                {% for product in products %}
                                                    <option value="{{ product.id }}">{{ product.name }}</option>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                           
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
</form>
```

Codes in routes.yaml file

```
controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../src/Controller/
        namespace: App\Controller
    type: attribute
home:
  path: /
  controller: App\Controller\HomeController::index
create:
  path: /create
  controller: App\Controller\MainController::create
test:
  path: /xavier
  controller: App\Controller\HomeController::index
product:
  path: /product
  controller: App\Controller\ProductController::index
```

Why am getting this error, when i tried to vardump the value of $product am gettinng data also. Why it is showing `Variable "products" does not exist` error

Am trying to load the page by

```
  http://127.0.0.1:8000/product
```

Comment: please share the route configs to see which route are you calling and which controller is used to render your templates. then you should name and show both twig files. there seem to be `product/index.html.twig` and `index.html.twig`. and there is a code smell in your controller. just return the products from the repository. and use twig to react if the products variable is empty.

Comment: @rickroyce I have ediited the file and getting same error

Comment: @Robbie both are same, what is the diffrence in both. I have also added the URL which am trying to load in question

Comment: @XavierIssac How are they both the same? You clearly made a typo: `['product' => $products]` VS `['products' => $products]`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There is your answer:

- you are calling this route `/product`
- your config here says use the ProductController with the index() method:

```yaml
product:
  path: /product
  controller: App\Controller\ProductController::index
```

the index controller renders the twig template with the following variables (controller_name):

```php
return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', [
    'controller_name' => 'ProductController',
]);
```

### solution:

change your product route to the show method to call the correct controller method:

```yaml
product:
  path: /product
  controller: App\Controller\ProductController::show
```

or put "products" as variable in the index() method:

```php
    //#[Route('/product', name: 'app_product')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $products = []; // insert products here 

        return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'ProductController',
            'products' => $products,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with routing what so ever. OP made a typo, see the commentrs

Comment: or put "products" as variable in the index() method: This will not works